# How to fix 'Unexpected identifier' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing code for a calculator and I got an error 'Unexpected Identifier' and I don't know what's wrong. The line of code is
alert("Welcome to the multiplication website!").

I have no idea what's wrong.

```
<head>
  <title>Multiplication Table</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Welcome to the multiplication website!")
    var rows = prompt("What is your first number?")
    var cols = prompt("What is your second number?")
        output = rows * cols
        if rows isNaN() 
        then output = Error: Not a Number
    document.write(output);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

I expected it to not have errors, then there were errors.
```

Comment: `if rows isNaN() 
        then output = Error: Not a Number` is not valid Javascript syntax.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to write Python in JavaScript. JS has a different syntax that is not whitespace aware ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have a little code that looks like pseudoxode - try this:

```
if (isNaN(rows)) alert("Error: Not a Number");
```